# Pass authenticated user through to API application within same IIS instance

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication

**ENVIRONMENT**

I have two applications, a client application which calls an API:

`ClientApplication.Web`
`My.Api`

Both are hosted in IIS as applications with their own App pools.
Both are set to use Windows Authentication with all other Auth options disabled.

**REQUIRMENTS**

Company policy is that the app pools must run under a service account `SRV\iis_sa`, so I set both app pools to run under that service account.

[image: app pools]

**BEHAVIOUR**

When I browse to `My.Api/swagger`, it prompts for credentials... I can call any of the controller methods, and using the debugger can see that `User.Identity.Name` is indeed `domain\MyName`..

When I browse to the `ClientApplication.Web` I input my credentials, which is fine. I see my `domain\MyName` in the top right hand side (displayed using `User.Identity.Name`)
This tells me that Windows Auth is working fine.

However when the `ClientApplication.Web` page loads, it calls the api immediately and I get an authentication error back. I can get past this error by setting the identity of the `ClientApplication.Web` app pool to `domain\MyName`..  This causes the `GetData` call to succeed.

When I then call an API controller method to called `ApproveRow`, which uses `User.Identity.Name` on the api side, it always logs `domain\MyName` as the user who performed the action (the same user account which is set in the app pool for the `ClientApplication.Web`). I have checked this with colleagues and it always logs my name, never their own name. I assume this is because the App pool identity is set to my name.

**QUESTION**

How do I pass the currently authenticated user from my web application to the api application in IIS?

OR

What setting do I need to change in IIS so the authenticated user in `ClientApplication.Web` gets passed so I can use `User.Identity.Name` (etc) in `My.Api`

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

(Or attempted to try...)

1. Tried all the built in accounts in the `ClientApplication.Web` app pool - LocalService, LocalSystem, NetworkService and ApplicationPoolIdentity (Any of these options produce the same authentication error as if I used `SRV\iis_sa`)
2. Enabled Impersonation in `My.Api` (Different error but seemed incompatible so steered away from this)
3. Enabled full control permissions on both application folders for `SRV\iis_sa` (Made no difference)
4. Tried to add `SRV\iis_sa` to `Impersonate a client after authentication` in Local Security Policy, however this is overridden by a GPO, and I'm not sure if it will help the issue.
5. Set `useAppPoolCredentials` to true for both applications, and all combinations of true/false for each. [image: useAppPoolCredentials]
6. In basic settings for each application, Connect as is set to pass-through authentication [image: pass through auth]

Maybe there is something simple I'm missing which I'd be grateful if someone could point it out.

Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible for you to achieve through iis, there will be a token in the Identity, you need to pass this token to another, but this can only be passed through code, iis cannot be directly.

Comment: How does it work then when the `ClientApplication.Web` app pool is set to `domain\MyName` (or a colleague's account) it passes that through to the api without any code change?

Comment: iis can’t do it, you can only pass code.